# MacOS: Changing screen capture location

Tags: osx, function, bash-functions

I make a lot of presentations that involve many screenshots, and I want an easier way to organize them by project. I'm trying to write a simple function that changes the location where screenshots are saved to the current working directory.

I've written a function in and saved it to `~/.my_custom_commands.sh`.

That file currently looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# changes location of screenshot to current directory
function shoothere() {
    defaults write com.apple.screencapture location '. '
    killall SystemUIServer
    echo 'foo'
    }
```

When I navigate to the directory where I want to save my screenshots and run the function, it does print `foo` but screenshots do not appear anywhere.

I've also tried replacing `'. '` with `$1` and running it as `$ shoothere .`, at which point I get an error `Rep argument is not a dictionary. Defaults have not been changed.` Googling this error message has gotten me precisely nowhere.

I'm on a Mac running Mojave 10.14.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This slightly different syntax appears to work for me; it's probably that `.` isn't correctly handled by the service MacOS has running in the background:

```
~/foo $ defaults write com.apple.screencapture location "$(pwd)"
~/foo $ defaults read com.apple.screencapture
{
    "last-messagetrace-stamp" = "576625649.15493";
    location = "/Users/[redacted]/foo";
}
```

To reset it back to default, you can use this:

```
$ defaults delete com.apple.screencapture location
```

`killall SystemUIServer` is not necessary at all, as soon as I ran the `defaults write` command, I was able to observe newly-captured screenshots appearing in the correct directory.

Comment: yes! thank you so much. works perfectly now.